# Connection with REST based JSON WebService from JQueryMobile

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, json, jquery-mobile

I am very new to JQuery and JQueryMobile.
Firstly, I would request you to help we with any link/tutorial to understand JQueryMobile and developing a Mobile Web App.

Secondly, Please provide some go-ahead on making a communication with a JSON WebService from my JQueryMobile Web Application.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to learn jQuery I would suggest watching these, It's free and gives a great in-depth look on how to use jQuery. After you have completed this you should be good to move into the jQueryMobile documentation below.

- http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/learn-jquery-in-30-days/

And for jQueryMobile

- http://jquerymobile.com
- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/

Answer (score 0):

List of links for jQuery mobile tutorials:
http://www.jqmgallery.com/jquery-mobile-tutorials/